# Create a multi-dimensional array in jquery with dynamic selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two selectors, each of which will select 3-5 elements.

```
var key = $('.inline-input input[type="textbox"]').val();
var val = $('select[name="create_icon"]').val();
```

These are part of a small inline form.  Once the values are entered, I need them to be stored in a multidimensional array.

I am currently using the `.map` method like so:

```
var array_val = 
  $('select[name="sr_badges_create_icon"], .inline-input input[type="textbox"]')
    .map(function() 
    {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
```

This returns a simple array. EDIT: As requested, this is the output of the map method:

```
["H", "fa-glass", "i", "fa-glass"]
```

However to process and manipulate this array of key value pairs in PHP, I need for the array to be stored in this format:

```
array( 0 => 
    array(  'key' => 'value',
            'key' => 'value'
    ),
array( 1 => 
    array(  'key' => 'value',
            'key' => 'value'
    ),
array( 2 => 
    array(  'key' => 'value',
            'key' => 'value'
    ),
);
```

I obviously am not very familiar with jquery yet, and I have spent over 2 hours trying to get this working with different variations of `$.each` or simple `for` loops. No success yet.

UPDATE: Functional [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nsjm1wfr/1/) of the current code.

Comment: Show the output of the map function.

Comment: can you post the related HTML, or better to create a fiddle, & show the expected output also.

Comment: also post the html too.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nsjm1wfr/1/

Comment: Posted a JSFiddle with a pretty functional example.  You can see what the JS saves.